# Re-write to_char function

Tags: oracle, performance, date, oracle12c

When I use to_char function, It's know as internal_function in EP, and Index can't work in this column. Are there any way to re-write it? I don't want to create a function based index

This is my predicates code.

```
TO_CHAR(createdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') = TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the reason we must use purely the date column on one side and a `trunc(sysdate)` like expression on the other instead of `TO_CHAR` while doing date comparisions.

```
where  createdate  >= trunc(sysdate) 
   and createdate  <  trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

Comment: Many thanks @Kaushik 
Although cost is the same but I can avoid create FBI.